# Does anyone know any SRS-resources for French learning?

Tags: ressources

Is there any sites or apps that use a spaced repetition technique (SR-system) for learning new words or grammar?

There are several examples I am really excited about ([WaniKani](https://www.wanikani.com/) - for Japenese Kanji, [Jalup NEXT](https://jalupnext.com/) - for learning Kanji as well as grammar, [Bunpro](https://bunpro.jp/) - specifically for Japanese grammar), but as you've already noticed they are all for learning Japanese. However, the results of not that long learning are quite impressive for me. One word, SRS just works for me.

So, I'm wondering about similar examples for French.

Comment: Duolingo is SRS and quite good overall if you set a high goal and stick to it daily.

Comment: I am not for it that much. I've already tried such sites as Duolingo, Memrise, busuu, Babbel and many more and I am not eager to use them, except Babbel, because it works good, but it's not free. Talking about apps, well, again, Babbel and Rosetta Stone are awesome for learning vocabulary, but they are not free. I've also tried a free app, Drops. It's great indeed. There is also MosaLingua. However, I haven't tried it out that much. Such a way, I am really interested in finding out some SR-resources for learning French grammar.

Answer (score 1):

[Clozemaster](https://www.clozemaster.com/languages/fra-eng/play?mode=multiple-choice&skill=vocabulary) might be what you're looking for. It uses an SRS system with cloze exercises.

Alternatively, [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) has many downloadable [decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/french) you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Anki (either via the excellent Android app or the desktop software) is a generic spaced repetition application. It has many free decks available, and I would suggest the following decks are especially good:

[Essential French](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/397151029) - this one concentrates on matching French terms with photos/images rather than with English (although does include English translations for most cards), building associations directly with concepts instead of going via a "third language".

[French A1 & A2](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/723355196) - this one has no English at all - just photos - and includes phrases as well as individual words.